# how to hide WSDL using CXF

Tags: cxf

i have developed a Java Web service using CXF, and Spring.
due to security reasons, i would like to hide the WSDL, though the WS will still be available.
is there a way to do that using CXF?

Comment: How does hiding the WSDL make it more secure?

Comment: WSDL documents a contract for a web service. If you don't publish it it's more difficult for aggressor to try to hack the web service. Of course it shouldn't be an only protection. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could add a servlet filter in web.xml that stops ?wsdl requests from being processed:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>wsdlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mycompany.myWsdlFilterClass</filter-class>    
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>wsdlFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*?wsdl</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The doFilter() method would look like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
    ServletException {

  String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getQueryString();    
  if(queryString!=null && queryString.toLowerCase().startsWith("wsdl")){
    return; //the filter chain stops and request does not get processed
  }
  else{
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

}
```

Comment: Does `filter-mapping` match query parameters? I'd be more likely to try stopping it from serving GET requests at all (SOAP goes by POST).

Comment: You can set the mapping to * which intercepts everything. In the filter class you can use ((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod(). if it returns POST, allow it thru (invoke chain.doFilter() ) and if not, then stop it (by not invoking it).